# I have the error: expected unqualified-id before 'if'

Tags: c++, compilation-errors

This is my Sketch or code:

```
const int EchoPin = 5;
const int TriggerPin = 6;
const int LedPin = 13; 

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(TriggerPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(EchoPin, INPUT);
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 int cm = ping(TriggerPin, EchoPin);
 Serial.print("Distancia: ");
 Serial.println(cm);
 delay(1000);
}

int ping(int TriggerPin, int EchoPin) {
 long duration, distanceCm;
 digitalWrite(TriggerPin, LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(4);
 digitalWrite(TriggerPin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(TriggerPin, LOW);
 duration = pulseIn(EchoPin, HIGH);
 distanceCm = duration * 10 / 292/ 2;
 return distanceCm;
}

if (distanceCm <= 20) {
 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}

if (distanceCm >= 20) {
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

The error appears in the second if.

Comment: Lean C syntax. *Code goes in functions!*

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because you have 2 **if** statements outside of a function. You could move them into the **ping()** function which would fix the error but there seems to be a logic error with the 2 if statements as well.

If **distanceCm** is 20, both if statements execute one right after another, so I doubt you'll see the LED turn on. Perhaps an **if/else** might work.

```
if(distanceCm < 21){
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}
else{
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is because you close your ping method  before the "if (distanceCm >= 20)" clausule. This is a correct code:

```
const int EchoPin = 5;
const int TriggerPin = 6;
const int LedPin = 13; 

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(TriggerPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(EchoPin, INPUT);
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 int cm = ping(TriggerPin, EchoPin);
 Serial.print("Distancia: ");
 Serial.println(cm);
 delay(1000);
}

int ping(int TriggerPin, int EchoPin) {
 long duration, distanceCm;
 digitalWrite(TriggerPin, LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(4);
 digitalWrite(TriggerPin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(TriggerPin, LOW);
 duration = pulseIn(EchoPin, HIGH);
 distanceCm = duration * 10 / 292/ 2;
  if (distanceCm <= 20) {
 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}

if (distanceCm >= 20) {
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
 return distanceCm;
}
```